# How to compare different objects in the same array in javascript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have sample data. I want to compare objects in array that i do not have all the data. if object not contain specific properties like in this given data i have missed params property in one object and rooms propertx missed in one object so i have to pull these two from common data.

What i have tried here

```
var emptyvar = [];

    var totalYears = hello.reduce(function (accumulator, pilot) {
      if (JSON.stringify(accumulator) != JSON.stringify(pilot)) {
        emptyvar.push(pilot)
      }
    });
```

but this compares whole object rather than only keys. How can i get missing data.

```
[  
       {  
          "coords":{  
             "lat":"52.5013632",
             "lon":"13.4174913"
          },
          "params":{  
             "rooms":"5",
             "value":"1000000"
          },
          "street":"Adalbertstraße 13"
       },
       {  
          "coords":{  
             "lat":"52.4888151",
             "lon":"13.3147011"
          },
          "params":{  
             "value":"1000000"
          },
          "street":"Brandenburgische Straße 10"
       },
       {  
          "coords":{  
             "lat":"52.5141632",
             "lon":"13.3780111"
          },
          "params":{  
             "rooms":"3",
             "value":"1500000"
          },
          "street":"Cora-Berliner-Straße 22"
       },
       {  
          "coords":{  
             "lat":"52.5336332",
             "lon":"13.4015613"
          },
          "street":"Fehrbelliner Straße 23"
       }
    ]
```

Comment: Please read here -> http://adripofjavascript.com/blog/drips/object-equality-in-javascript.html

Answer (score 1):

There are a bunch of json schema validators out there, one of them popular at this time is [ajv](https://github.com/epoberezkin/ajv)

you can find an example working with your schema, you can tweak it depending on which properties are required and whether additional keys can be accepted

```
const schema = {
    $id: 'home',
    properties: {

        coords: {
            properties: {
                lat: { type: 'string' },
                lon: { type: 'string' }
            },
            required: ['lat', 'lon']
        },

        params: {
            properties: {
                rooms: { type: 'string' },
                value: { type: 'string' }
            }
        },

        street: { type: 'string' }
    },

    required: ['coords', 'params', 'street'],
    additionalProperties: false
};

const ajv = new Ajv({
    schemas: [schema]
});

let data = { 
  coords:{  
     lat: "52.5013632",
     lon:"13.4174913"
  },
  params:{  
     rooms:"5",
     value:"1000000"
  },
  street:"Adalbertstraße 13"
};


console.log(ajv.validate(schema, data));
```